# How to add tab completion to a Nodejs CLI app

Tags: javascript, node.js, autocomplete, command-line-interface

I want to add tab completion to a Nodejs CLI app (And preferably generate the tab completion dynamically).

I found a few npm modules but not sure how to really implement them:

https://github.com/hij1nx/complete

https://github.com/mklabs/node-tabtab

So what I am looking for is so I can have a nodejs file that is something like:

```
my-cmd create arg1 arg2
```

But then I might want to autocomplete like:

```
my-cmd cr<tab> -> create
```

Thanks!

Comment: This is not something implemented in your app but within the shell the user uses.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/95211/how-do-i-set-up-bash-completion-for-command-arguments for how `bash` does this.

Comment: I'm on the same situation. Already found several `npm` modules to handle completion but I can't figure out how to run the examples.

Comment: @diosney. So I have started working on a project that has it in. https://github.com/Jonovono/um. I'll submit a fuller answer of how I am achieving this as well.

Answer (score 21):

Use [omelette](https://www.npmjs.com/package/omelette) package that I built. If you have any questions, please contact me.

Answer (score 6):

## Edit - fast answer

After I answered, I kept reading tabtab source a bit and noticed that I can also run

```
 pkgname completion install
```

to install the completion. since my environment was already dirty, I don't know if it actually did anything, but seems to me like it did..

## Longer answer

@CameronLittle has given great documentation.

For the impatient, you can start by running

```
sudo bash -c 'pkgname completion > /etc/bash_completion.d/pkgname'
source /etc/bash_completion.d/pkgname
```

This will add completion to your current bash session.

As far as I know, new sessions will get the completion automatically.

To make the process seamless for user, you can use the `install` and `postinstall` hooks in package.json

https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts

Make sure to not print anything by default. means running `pkgname` should result in no output, or otherwise it will not work.

## important! install tabtab only from master

It seems tabtab has an annoying bug that was resolved in master but never got into a release..

The relevant commit to fix it is this: 
https://github.com/mklabs/node-tabtab/commit/f8473555bf7278a300eae31cbe3377421e2eeb26

which handles completion for strings starting with `--`.

The commit if from february 2014, however the latest release as of (Jan. 2015) is 0.0.2 from Jan. 2014.. I assume there will not be more releases.

So if you want to get this fix, and you should(!), install tabtab only from master.

don't waste 2 hours figuring out what you did wrong like me :)

## How did i reach this answer? TL;DR

While @CameronLittle's answer gives the explanation behind the scene, I would like to explain how to I reached the answer.

I tried using the package `tabtab` which has an explicit section about installing it. see https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabtab#completion-install

However, that didn't seem to work for me.

Looking at the code they instruct to add, I see the following `process.argv.slice(2)[0] === 'completion'` which made me run the command `pkgname completion`, which outputs something that starts with

```
###-begin-pkgname-completion-###
### credits to npm, this file is coming directly from isaacs/npm repo
#
# Just testing for now. (trying to learn this cool stuff)
#
# npm command completion script
#
# Installation: pkgname completion >> ~/.bashrc  (or ~/.zshrc)
#
```

the words `this file is coming directly from isaacs/npm repo` made me wonder more. following the other answer here, I looked at /etc/bash_completion.d/npm - which showed the same exact content.. and so the comment.

I decided to run

```
pkgname completion > /etc/bash_completion.d/pkgname
```

however that requires sudo permissions and so becomes

```
sudo bash -c "pkgname completion > /etc/bash_completion.d/pkgname
```

and then, in order to apply it to current bash session I had to run

```
 source /etc/bash_completion.d/pkgname
```

and voila! it works!

when I tried to open another terminal, it still worked, so I assume it will apply to all users. if not - you should add it to .bashrc or something..

Answer (score 5):

I would just like to add that there is a 
[npm package yargs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs#completion-cmd-description-fn) that enables bash-completion shortcuts for commands and options.

It has the option to output a .bashrc completion script. Bash completions are then enabled by sourcing the generated script.

It is currently an actively maintained package on npm with over a million downloads a month.